# requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL with ArtifactoryPath

Tags: python, artifactory

I am trying to deploy and download files from artifactory using the artifactory python module and it keeps throwing an error.

From the module page(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/artifactory/0.1.17) it gives the following example:

```
from artifactory import ArtifactoryPath
path = ArtifactoryPath(
   "http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/distributions/org/apache/tomcat/apache-
tomcat-7.0.11.tar.gz")

with path.open() as fd:
    with open("tomcat.tar.gz", "wb") as out:
        out.write(fd.read())
```

When I try to do that with the repo I'm working with using the following code:

```
from artifactory import ArtifactoryPath
path = ArtifactoryPath("https://artifactory.path.to.repo/file.tar.gz")

with path.open() as fd:
    with open("test_artifact.tar.gz", "wb") as fh:
        fh.write(fd.read())
```

I get the following error:

```
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'https:/artifactory.path.to.repo/file.tar.gz': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://artifactory.path.to.repo/file.tar.gz?
```

I don't understand why it keeps stripping off a '/' from 'https://'. I even tried just adding the "http://" in front of the url just to see what it would do, but then it just gives:

```
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'http:/https:/artifactory.path.to.repo/file.tar.gz': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://http:/https:/artifactory.path.to.repo/file.tar.gz?
```

Has anybody seen/dealt with this error before when using the artifactory module?

EDIT: I'm using Windows 10 and Python3.5

Comment: What OS are you on, and what version of Python? There could easily be a bug in the way the library interacts with the `pathlib` library, depending on the platform you are on, and the path is being normalised (double slashes removed).

Comment: I'd advice you to file a report with the project. Include all relevant info, including any configuration files.